# when I run my TCL script is there a way I can add a command or a variable with my run command?

Tags: tcl

What I am trying to do is run my TCL script with a variable.

So for example lets say my script was called example.tcl.

I want to be able to run that script doing something like this:

```
tclsh example.tcl success
```

Then in my tcl script I will have:

```
set status = variable  <---- this variable should be equal to "success"
puts $status
```

Is there anyway in TCL I can do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to `tclsh` after the script name are stored as a list in the global `argv` variable.

```
set status [lindex $argv 0]
puts "status = $status"
```

The length of the list is in `argc`, but nobody really uses that. The script is in `argv0`, not in `argv`; that's very convenient sometimes.